# How to get insight into an EKS Kubernetes version update error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In the EKS web console, it gives me the following warning at the top of the dashboard:
"This cluster is running the oldest Kubernetes version currently supported by Amazon EKS.
Ensure that your cluster is updated before the version end of support date."  And it has a "Update now" button.  But every time I try to update, it fails silently.  No errors or logs to go on.

When I select the button, it shows me that I am able to update from Kubernetes 1.22 to 1.23.  After clicking Update, the status of the cluster changes to "Updating" for a couple minutes, but then back to "Active".  And the version is still at 1.22.  In the "Update history" tab, I can see the failed attempt.  It has an Update ID, Submission time, Type, and Status.  The type is VersionUpdate, and Status is Failed.  When I click on it, the Error count is zero, and no errors are displayed.  Only a status of Failed.  How can I find out why the upgrade failed?

Further details:

- I enabled all the Control plane logging.  Nothing in those logs give me any insight into the upgrade attempts.
- I tried doing the upgrade via the browser console, aws cli, and eksctl command.  They all fail the same way.
- My AWS profile is in the admin group, and so has the AdministratorAccess profile attached to it.  Also, I was able to upgrade from 1.21 to 1.22 without problem, so I don't think it's a permissions problem.

Here's the output of a `aws eks describe-update`:

```
    "update": {
    "id": "cbb53f20-b5e2-4cf0-b95a-f6634e71b9de",
    "status": "Failed",
    "type": "VersionUpdate",
    "params": [
        {
            "type": "Version",
            "value": "1.23"
        },
        {
            "type": "PlatformVersion",
            "value": "eks.6"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": 1680798494.173,
    "errors": []
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is dangerously close to [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a _programming_ stack exchange site; that said, have you checked the cloudtrail logs for errors? is your console user the owner of the EKS cluster (since EKS is a snowflake that way)? have you tried issuing the upgrade action using awscli? Don't use the comments to provide further details, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75951163/edit) and include them

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidance in this [checklist](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-plan-upgrade-cluster) first. Check to see whether you have enough available IP addresses (at least 5) and your SGs and IAM permissions are correct. For additional information see, [Updating an Amazon EKS cluster Kubernetes version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-cluster.html). If the upgrade still fails after that, open a case with AWS Support.